# Uniform generation of permutation with repetition at most k times?

Tags: algorithm, random, language-agnostic, permutation, uniform

We have set `{1, 2, 3, ...,n}` of numbers. We want to generate permutation of length of m created of those numbers with repetition of each number at most `k` times.

If we assume `n=5, k=2, m=3`, then we could receive: `{3,3,1}`, but not `{3, 3, 3}` as `3` in the second example happens to be three times in output, which is more than k.

Is there a way of uniform generation of such permutation in a fast way?

I tried two different solutions.

First:

1) generate random permutation with repetition, there is `n^m` different permutations.

2) check if this is a correct permutation (if it does not contain more than `k` times the same number

3) if yes, then return, else go to 1)

Python snippet:

```
import numba
import numpy as np


@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def gen_sequence1(n, k, m):
    result = np.random.randint(0, n, (1, m))[0]
    while not is_correct(result, k):
        result = np.random.randint(0, n, (1, m))[0]
    return result


@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def most_frequent(iter):
    return np.bincount(iter).max()


@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def is_correct(pruf, k):
    return most_frequent(pruf) <= k
```

Second method:

Generate random integer, add it to sequence only if it didn't show up before `k` times. Optimized version of these words is below presented (written in Python).
Python snippet:

```
def gen_seq(n, d, m):
    choices = list(range(n))
    degrees = [0] * n
    result = []
    k = n - 1
    for i in range(m):
        rand = np.random.randint(0, k)
        result.append(choices[rand])
        degrees[choices[rand]] += 1
        if degrees[choices[rand]] == d:
            choices[rand], choices[k] = choices[k], choices[rand]
            k -= 1
    return result
```

Problem is that the first method is very slow for `n=30, m=28, d=1` it needs `10^9` times to generate sequence, which is pretty obvious.

The second one is not generating uniform permutations (some have bigger probabilities than others).

Do you have any ideas how one could generate such sequence fast and uniformly?

Comment: Does not have to be in Python. I am looking for more an idea, than program at all.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes you have enough memory to hold the numbers [1..n] k times.

1. Set up the array [1..n].
2. Duplicate the array k times: [1..n, 1..n, 1..n, ... 1..n] into a large array.
3. Run the first m steps of a [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) on the large duplicated array to get your required permutation.  There is no need to shuffle the entire array since you only need m numbers.

Comment: Does not return uniformly random permutations. Having list [1, 2, 1, 2] and m=2 I receive probabilities: (1, 1) -> 1/6, (2, 2) -> 1/6, (1, 2) -> 2/6, (2, 1) -> 2/6

Comment: Try checking that your F-Y shuffle code is working correctly.  You need to move elements in the large array so they can only be picked once.  Does it shuffle [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] correctly?  Also have a look at the output from your RNG; is it showing a pattern?  Some simple RNGs alternate odd and even numbers for instance.

Comment: @rossum: (comment revised) No, OP is right. Your algorithm is not uniform. Suppose you compute all 2n! permutations of [1..2n] and look at the first two numbers in each permutation. Would you prefer to bet that both numbers have the same parity or that they have different parities? Answer: (b). There are 2n(2n-1) pairs; of those n(n-1) are both even and n(n-1) are both odd, while n² are even/odd and n² are odd/even. So different parity is n/(n-1) more likely than same parity. This is particularly obvious if n is 2, as in OP's example above.

Comment: Of course, this depends on the precise definition of "uniform".

Comment: By uniform I meant that any pair of possible configurations has the same probability.

Answer (score 0):

If i remember correctly np.choice have a options to give probabilities then you can do somthing like this:

1. Set up the array [1..n].
2. Duplicate the array k times: [1..n, 1..n, 1..n, ... 1..n] into a large array.
   just like @rossum proposed.
3. Generate probabilities for this large array uniform (1/(k*n)).

Repeat m times:

4. Get one number to result array
5. Set Probabilities that for drawned item probability will be 0 and for rest with the 
   same value spread between them uniformly 1/(k*n) that we just set to 0

Example:

Let S=[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4] be a large array with k of each items inside, k=3 and m = 4.

1. generate P = [1/12]*len(S)
2. result = random(S,P) Let assume result = [1]
3. Probabilities  will be like this P = [0,1/12+1/36,1/12+1/36,1/12+1/36,rest remain the same]

Repeat steps 2 and 3 m times

if there is no more values that are the same as the drawn set it to 0 and make rest probabilities to keep this ration and sum to 1 . i think the hardest part will be manipulating probabilities.

Comment: How did you come up with such probabilities? I need uniformly distributed, and it does not look like it would be uniform.

Comment: To every other 1 on S you need to add probabulity like 1/3*1/12 to make it sum to 1 and to compensate probability other solutions can be array with counters for each value if counter ==k then remove that value from array and draw next number